# Compile multiple SASS files into a single CSS file

Tags: npm, sass, compilation, node-sass

I am using node-sass to compile all my scss files into a single .css file.

Using this npm script:

```
"scss": "node-sass -o css css -w"
```

The problem is that script creates a file for every .scss file I have and not a single file for all the css.

What's wrong with that script and how can I achieve what I want?

Comment: Why not just create a single `scss` file with only imports to all the files to merge?

Comment: Hmmm. Good point! By the way, is there a way to output the css file to the root folder? Or it is not allowed?

Comment: To the root folder? The root of your project? User home? Disk/mount root? Specify :)

Comment: Create your scss files, name them beginning with a _. IE: _links.scss. Sass will not compile that. Create 1 scss file that imports all your _scss files, and that will compile to CSS. Do not use the _ on the main scss file that will be compiled

Comment: Thanks Brad! Got it working!